# Docker use Host VPN during build

Tags: docker, openvpn

I am trying to install a repo coming from my company VPN-protected gitlab server during docker build. I have tried running openvpn and connecting to VPN server unsuccessfuly, due to the following error:

```
Wed Nov 26 12:41:10 2014 OpenVPN 2.3.2 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [eurephia] [MH] [IPv6] built on Feb  4 2014
Wed Nov 26 12:41:10 2014 Control Channel Authentication: using 'ta.key' as a OpenVPN static key file
Wed Nov 26 12:41:10 2014 Outgoing Control Channel Authentication: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Wed Nov 26 12:41:10 2014 Incoming Control Channel Authentication: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Wed Nov 26 12:41:10 2014 Socket Buffers: R=[212992->200000] S=[212992->200000]
Wed Nov 26 12:41:10 2014 UDPv4 link local: [undef]
Wed Nov 26 12:41:10 2014 UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]<REMOVED_IP>:1194
Wed Nov 26 12:41:10 2014 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]<REMOVED_IP>:1194, sid=2a06a918 c4ecc6df
Wed Nov 26 12:41:11 2014 VERIFY OK: depth=1, CN=OpenVPN CA
Wed Nov 26 12:41:11 2014 VERIFY OK: nsCertType=SERVER
Wed Nov 26 12:41:11 2014 VERIFY OK: depth=0, CN=OpenVPN Server
Wed Nov 26 12:41:11 2014 Data Channel Encrypt: Cipher 'BF-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
Wed Nov 26 12:41:11 2014 Data Channel Encrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Wed Nov 26 12:41:11 2014 Data Channel Decrypt: Cipher 'BF-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
Wed Nov 26 12:41:11 2014 Data Channel Decrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Wed Nov 26 12:41:11 2014 Control Channel: TLSv1, cipher TLSv1/SSLv3 DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, 2048 bit RSA
Wed Nov 26 12:41:11 2014 [OpenVPN Server] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]54.173.232.46:1194
Wed Nov 26 12:41:14 2014 SENT CONTROL [OpenVPN Server]: 'PUSH_REQUEST' (status=1)
Wed Nov 26 12:41:14 2014 PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REPLY,explicit-exit-notify,topology subnet,route-delay 5 30,dhcp-pre-release,dhcp-renew,dhcp-release,route-metric 101,ping 12,ping-restart 50,comp-lzo yes,redirect-private def1,redirect-private bypass-dhcp,redirect-private autolocal,redirect-private bypass-dns,route-gateway 172.16.224.129,route 172.16.1.0 255.255.255.0,route 172.16.224.0 255.255.255.0,block-ipv6,ifconfig 172.16.224.131 255.255.255.128'
Wed Nov 26 12:41:14 2014 Unrecognized option or missing parameter(s) in [PUSH-OPTIONS]:4: dhcp-pre-release (2.3.2)
Wed Nov 26 12:41:14 2014 Unrecognized option or missing parameter(s) in [PUSH-OPTIONS]:5: dhcp-renew (2.3.2)
Wed Nov 26 12:41:14 2014 Unrecognized option or missing parameter(s) in [PUSH-OPTIONS]:6: dhcp-release (2.3.2)
Wed Nov 26 12:41:14 2014 Unrecognized option or missing parameter(s) in [PUSH-OPTIONS]:18: block-ipv6 (2.3.2)
Wed Nov 26 12:41:14 2014 OPTIONS IMPORT: timers and/or timeouts modified
Wed Nov 26 12:41:14 2014 OPTIONS IMPORT: explicit notify parm(s) modified
Wed Nov 26 12:41:14 2014 OPTIONS IMPORT: LZO parms modified
Wed Nov 26 12:41:14 2014 OPTIONS IMPORT: --ifconfig/up options modified
Wed Nov 26 12:41:14 2014 OPTIONS IMPORT: route options modified
Wed Nov 26 12:41:14 2014 OPTIONS IMPORT: route-related options modified
Wed Nov 26 12:41:14 2014 ROUTE_GATEWAY 192.168.0.1/255.255.255.0 IFACE=wlan0 HWADDR=c4:85:08:c9:14:f4
Wed Nov 26 12:41:14 2014 ERROR: Cannot ioctl TUNSETIFF tun: Operation not permitted (errno=1)
Wed Nov 26 12:41:14 2014 Exiting due to fatal error
```

I am able to connect in the docker container at runtime, but not during buildtime, if I specify `--device=/dev/net/tun` as part of docker run. There seems to be no way to replicate this during docker build, so I am trying to use the host network since I am actively connected to the VPN.
I have tried this (with the appropriate info):

- `docker build --network=host --add-host <gitlab URL>:<gitlab IP> .`
- setting the subnet to /28 instead of /24 -> this bricked my docker install (macOS)

Similarly, this does not work. Any ideas on how to go about this during docker build would be very appreciated. I ultimately am doing this so that I may pip install from a git repository, which could be installed then copied in to the docker build environment. My problem with this is that it causes some differences between the developer and docker build for installing pip requirements, but if that is the 'right' way then so be it.

Edit: I've gotten a little further, albeit using host VPN connection. However, I am now having issues with git + ssh having host key verification error. I have confirmed that the private key git is using is the correct md5 hash as the public key uploaded to gitlab, and I am adding my gitlab server to the known hosts and printing that out to see that it matches my real system's known hosts as well. I have also added --trusted-host `my gitlab url` to no luck either.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was adding my gitlab server to the docker's known hosts via `ssh-keyscan gitlab.xyz.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts` - this was not enough, but running `ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no git@gitlab.xyz.com` is. Adding this prior to pulling my pip requirements from my gitlab server was enough to solve my issue, though I am not sure why manually adding it to known hosts was not working.